# How to pass a column of file names to mutate and return the number of columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I have the following function

```r
colr <- function(file){
  a <- file %>% 
    read_xlsx() 

  ncol(a)
}
```

I would like to pass a tibble -- which contains a column of my excel file names to this function and make a new column which tells me the number of columns in the excel spreadsheet.

so my tibble(file.list) is

```
> file.list
   <chr>
   file_a.xlsx
   file_b.xlsx
   file_c.xlsx
```

I would like the following

```
> file.list       ncols
   <chr>          <int>
   file_a.xlsx      10
   file_b.xlsx      10
   file_c.xlsx       2
```

This is what I tried

```
tibble(file.list) %>% 
  mutate(ncols =  colr(file.list))
```

but I got the error

> Error: `path` must be a string

then I tried using `quo`

```
tibble(file.list) %>% 
  mutate(ncols =  colr(quo(file.list)))
```

I ended up with the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing to check does it work for `file.list[1] %>% 
    read_xlsx(.,range = cell_cols("A:Z")) %>% ncol ` ? Also you might need to include full path of the xlsx files.

Comment: Does `colr` work when you pass it a single filename as a string? E.g., `colr("file_a.xlsx")`.

Comment: I do get an integer returned with `colr("file_a.xlsx")`

Comment: @RonakShah `file.list[1] %>% read_xlsx() %>% ncol` works

Comment: Using `purrr` and `dplyr`, does this code run? `tibble(file.list) %>% mutate(ncols =  map_int(file.list, colr))`

Comment: That did it @Lyngbakr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comment by @Lyngbakr we can use `map_int` or `rowwise` for each `file.list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tibble::tibble(file.list) %>% 
       mutate(ncols =  map_int(file.list, colr))


tibble::tibble(file.list) %>% 
         rowwise() %>%
         mutate(ncols =  colr(file.list))
```

Comment: `colr` returns an integer, so wouldn't it be `map_int`?

Comment: yes `map_int` would be better. Also I noticed that you posted the comment earlier. I don't mind deleting the answer. You can post it as your answer. :)

Comment: It was pretty much the same time, so no need to delete! Thanks, though.